# What is use of making classes serializable?

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization, pojo

1. I have noticed many of the library classes "ArrayList", "String" even the exceptions are having a serialVersionUID. Why they have made it like this. Whats the practical use of doing that.FYI I am familiar with the concept of Serialization. Please point out the practical purpose of it.

For your reference find the serialversionUid for ClassCastException

```
public class ClassCastException extends RuntimeException {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -9223365651070458532L;
```

Where these object's state going to persist? And where will these objects state going to be retrieved ?

2. I am currently working in a project where we are making REST controllers whose input and output parameters will be JSON.We are creating simple POJOs for i/p and o/p parameters.I have seen people making those POJOs serializable .Whats the point in doing that ?

But I havent seen `**out.readObject**` or **out.writeobject** which is used to write and read the state of object.Will the POJO's state persist just making it serializable? If yes where it will be stored?

Comment: *Will the POJO's state persist just making it serializable?* No, it is persistable. *If yes where it will be stored?* Wherever you store it.

Comment: "Please point out the practical purpose of it." -- so that they can be serialized? Such as for storage in a file, or transfer over the network with RMI, etc.

Comment: In my second qs the POJOs are just made serializable. Nothing is written to persist it.I have mentioned this in qs. So it wont be persisting automatically.right? And plz answer both my questions if you can .

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt in my first qs I have mentioned in libarary classes String is serializable.But why would we do that. Bcz we normally want to persist state of an Object not a particular variable. Is their any code written inside JVM which persists all the "Strings". Because where is the code to read and write the state of object. ?

Comment: @smrutiranjan There doesn't have to be any.  Serialization happens automatically without any special code; you just have to implement `Serializable`.  You don't have to write any other code for an object to be serializable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Only writing a class as "Searializable" makes it eligible for serialization,but not serializaing it(save the states of the object )automatically. R u trying to say that when a class implements "Serializable" it automaticaaly gets serialized without writing any code to save it

Comment: @smrutiranjan yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.  Java automatically takes care of that for you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're missing OPs point/confusion. Adding [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) to a class makes it *eligible* for serialization, with Java Runtime providing a default serialization strategy. It does not however serialize the object without writing further code. You still have to actually call [`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)) for the serialization to happen.

Comment: @Andreas I disagree with your reading of the OP; it does not sound to me like they understand that the Java runtime provides a default serialization strategy.

Comment: @LouisWasserman  Can u plz provide something which will prove your argument...Bcz I am getting too much confused here

Comment: Try adding Serializable to random POJOs.  It will just work.  Or look at the links in the answer already provided.

Comment: @LouisWasserman how to check that it works? I mean where should i search for the saved states of the POJO, as I am not writing anycodes to save it ?

Comment: Make an object implement Serializable, write it somewhere with an ObjectOutputStream, read it back with an ObjectInputStream.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Bro that was the point me and Andreas trying to make that without writing codes to save the state wont save the states automatically..U can refer our earlier points

Comment: @Andreas would u like to comment anything on the topic ?

Comment: What do you mean? The point of making an object implement Serializable is that you just have to call ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(o) and it will save all the state of o automatically without any extra effort. That's the point of Serializable, to make that automatically work. To make it super easy to write an object out to a stream, rather than having to go through each individual field of an object. That's the whole point. What aren't you getting here?

Comment: R u trying to say that when a class implements "Serializable" it automaticaaly gets serialized without writing any code to save it -----I have asked u this in an earlier comment....Adding Serializable to a class makes it eligible for serialization, with Java Runtime providing a default serialization strategy. It does not however serialize the object without writing further code. You still have to actually call ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object obj) for the serialization to happen...thats what andreas told u ..................and u disagreed

Comment: @LouisWasserman It might be a misunderstanding...Now that u also agree....my confusion is clear.....Thanks for giving time

Comment: I agreed with what Andreas said about Serializable, I thought he was wrong about what he thought you were saying.

Comment: Lol .."I thought he was wrong about what he thought you were saying"....So much thought.....:)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the full story, read the spec: [Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html).

> [...] many of the library classes "ArrayList", "String" even the exceptions are having a serialVersionUID. Why they have made it like this.

To support backwards compatibility when reading objects that were written in an older version of the class. See [Stream Unique Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#a4100).

> Where these object's state going to persist?

Wherever you decide. See [Writing to an Object Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4176).

> And where will these objects state going to be retrieved ?

Wherever you put it. See [Reading from an Object Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4188).

> [...] input and output parameters will be JSON. [...] I have seen people making those POJOs serializable. Whats the point in doing that ?

None. JSON is not using Java serialization. Java serialization creates a binary stream. JSON creates text.

> Will the POJO's state persist just making it serializable? If yes where it will be stored?

No, see above.